# evaluating two inputs and one output model tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pre-trained-model, ensemble-learning

I am trying to evaluate a model with 2 inputs and 1 output, each input goes to separate pretrained model and then the output from both the models get averaged. I am using the same data for both the inputs.

```
test_dir = 'D:\Graduation_project\Damage type not collected'



test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,)




test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical',
                                            batch_size = 16, 
                                            target_size=(150,150))

test_set1 = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical',
                                            batch_size = 16, 
                                            target_size=(150,150))
```

loading first model and renaming the layers

```
def load_dense_model():
    densenet = tf.keras.models.load_model('D:\Graduation_project\saved models\damage_type_model.h5', compile=False)
    
    for i, layer in enumerate(densenet.layers):
        layer._name = 'Densenet_layer' + str(i)
    return densenet
```

loading second model

```
def load_vgg19_model():
    vgg19 = tf.keras.models.load_model('D:\Graduation_project\saved models\damage_type_VGG19.h5', compile=False)
     
    return vgg19
```

creating ensemble model

```
def ensamble_model(first_model, second_model):
    densenet = first_model()
    vgg19 = second_model()

    output_1 = densenet.get_layer('Densenet_layer613')
    output_2 = vgg19.get_layer('dense_4')
    
    avg = tf.keras.layers.Average()([output_1.output, output_2.output])
    
    
    model = Model(inputs=[densenet.input, vgg19.input], outputs=avg)
    
    return model

METRICS = [ 
     'accuracy',
      tf.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      tf.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      tf.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      tf.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      tf.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      tf.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
      tfa.metrics.F1Score(name='F1_Score', num_classes=5),
      tfa.metrics.MultiLabelConfusionMatrix(num_classes=5)
 
]

model = ensamble_model(load_dense_model, load_vgg19_model)
```

compiling and evaluating the model

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss ='binary_crossentropy', 
                  metrics = 'accuracy')

model.evaluate({'Densenet_layer0':test_set1, 'input_2':test_set})
```

evaluate() fails to run

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"} values), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your model complaining because you are feeding a `dict`/`list` of iterators that yield an image each, instead of feeding an iterator that yields the image twice (once for each model).

What would happen if you wrap your `DirectoryIterator` on a generator that can feed the data correctly?

```py
def gen_itertest(test_dir):
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical',
                                            batch_size = 16, 
                                            target_size=(150,150))
    for i in range(len(test_set)):
         x = test_set.next()
         yield [x[0], x[0]], x[1] # Twice the input, only once the label
```

and then you can feed this to the evaluate

```py
testset = gen_itertest('D:\Graduation_project\Damage type not collected')
result = model.evaluate(testset)
```

I am not sure this will work but because you haven't provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I am not going to do one to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the evaluate() like this:

```
result = model.evaluate(x=[test_set1, test_set])
```

Then you could get the name of the metrics doing something like this:

```
dict(zip(model.metrics_names, result))
```

Comment: This error shows up ` ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'> `